# Unique identifier in SMS-based two factor authentification (mobile app)

Tags: android, ios, authentication, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile phone application. "Sign up" / "Sign in" mechanism should be implemented without entering any username/password pair and will be based on 2F authentification via the SMS confirmation code.

Common way of an implementation this functionality is pretty easy. The user enters the phone number during registration, the server sends him the one time confirmation code. Then the user sends received code and the server verifies it. If everything is ok, the phone receives access token, saves it in a phone memory/DB/local storage and uses this token per each HTTP request to API.

It's not a problem to implement such way of authentification, but I wondered about the additional security.

**What can be additionally sended with confirmation code from the mobile phone?** Maybe phone MAC address (certainly if it's possible), randomly generated string (like a hash) or any other unique identifier. When the confirmation code and this the second parameter are sended, the server will save their and will use to verify further requests.

By the way, I develop a hybrid mobile app with Ionic Framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apple made sure with iOS 7 that no hardware identifiers are available to developers. So no MAC address can be read from the device. An `UUID` store in the keychain would be you best bet. Otherwise you idea sounds very solid.

Comment: you can generate a random key from within your app.

Comment: You can create the SHA1 or SHA256 based hash string.